# Does current row a window frame clause include equal rows?

Tags: sql, vertica

When using a window frame clause with a range we define the start point and the end point of the window we aggregate over. If we order by something that has multiple rows for a value the actual row processed is not deterministic and will be somewhere within this set. So will the result include all rows with the same value as current row as well in this case?

https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AnalyzingData/SQLAnalytics/WindowFraming.htm Does not mention this explicitly but seems to hint at it being the actual non-deterministic row.

So if I have the following table t:

```
| ts                | x     |
|------------------ |---    |
| 2017-11-29 10:00  | 1     |
| 2017-11-30 10:00  | 2     |
| 2017-11-30 11:00  | 3     |
| 2017-12-01 11:00  | 4     |
```

and the following query:

```
with results as (
select
sum(x) over (order by ts::date range between current row and unbounded following) as r
from t
)
select r from results where ts = '2017-11-30 11:00'
```

will it say 9 (2+3+4) or will it say either 9 or 7 depending on the how the ordering took place?

How do I include all items with the same value in my window as well?

Answer (score 0):

So when just getting all data from the results you are actually able to test this using the following query:

```
with results as (
select
sum(x) over (order by ts::date range between current row and unbounded following) as r
from t
)
select r from results
```

The results are:
r 10 9 9 4 and the two 9's in there mean that it actually includes the whole date since it can't order any further, not just the current row.

I tested this using sqlfiddle on Postgres 9.6 and in Vertica 8.1 directly in the database.